# Facebook graph: Batch parameter must be a JSON array

Tags: php, json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Yesterday my script was working fine to do batch requests.

Today for any reason, it's not working...

I have this error:

"GraphBatchException: Batch parameter must be a JSON"

When I check my logs I have this:

```
$urlPost="?batch=[{"method":"POST","body":"message=100+rembours%C3%A9+sur+votre+1er+pari+%3A+http%3A%2F%2Fbit.ly%2Fbonus514%0D%0A","relative_url":"%2F285944461555097%2Fphotos%3Fpublished%3Dfalse%26url%3Dhttps%3A%2F%2Ffbcdn-sphotos-e-a.akamaihd.net%2Fhphotos-ak-xpa1%2Ft1.0-9%2F10517958_336601306489412_5656239420132644534_n.png%26scheduled_publish_time%3D1405873800%26access_token%3Dxxx";
```

So I don't see what's wrong as it was working yesterday. Any idea?

Comment: I'm having the same issue... works with curl for some reason though so I'm really baffled. I'm making the http POST request in node.

Comment: @ArdentKid Check if sometimes you don't have any invisible characters (tabs or useless spaces). Also some special characters (big arrows or €õ²|) may cause issues.

Comment: This answer works like a charm: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056097/facebook-batch-api-insight-requests/10063867#10063867

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Facebook Batch API insight requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056097/facebook-batch-api-insight-requests)