# Facebook graph API batch request

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am using Node js to make a batch request to Facebook for fetching the details of certain campaigns in my account.
I have created the batch and tried posting it to FB, but everytime the error i receive 'Batch parameter must be a JSON array'.

```
 var urlfinal = '/?access_token=' + [access_token];
batch = [{

      "method": "GET",
      "relative_url": "/v3.1/[campaignid]/insights?fields=spend,impressions,reach,clicks,cpm,cpc,cpp,ctr,unique_ctr,unique_clicks&time_range={'since':'2012-01-01','until':'2018-09-31'}&time_increment=monthly"

    }, {

      "method": "GET",
      "relative_url": "/v3.1/[campaignid]/insights?fields=spend,impressions,reach,clicks,cpm,cpc,cpp,ctr,unique_ctr,unique_clicks&time_range={'since':'2012-01-01','until':'2018-09-31'}&time_increment=monthly"

    }];

url = urlfinal + '&batch=' + JSON.stringify(batch);

    var options = {
      host: 'graph.facebook.com',
      path: url,
      method: 'POST'
    };

 var req = https.request(options, function(res) {
      // console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
      // console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
      //res.setEncoding('utf8');
      var body = '';
      res.on('data', function(chunk) {
        // console.log("body:" + chunk);
        body += chunk;

      });
      res.on('end', function() {
        var fbRes = JSON.parse(body);
        console.log(fbRes);
      });
    });
```

Comment: Try to url encode all the `relative_url`s like: `"relative_url": encodeURI("/v3.1/[campaignid]/i...")` see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10056097/facebook-batch-api-insight-requests/10063867#10063867

Comment: Or entire `batch` array `encodeURI(JSON.stringify(batch))`

Comment: @Molda Thanks. But both of them had the same error.

Comment: Examples in the manual use cURL `-F` syntax to post those values, which means it will create a multipart/form-data request. Try to match that with your node code - send the data as part of the request body, not URL parameters, and add the necessary Content-Type header, if that doesn’t happen automatically.